# OS X Safari Comodo SSL issue

Tags: macos, safari, certificate, ssl

[image: alert]

Strange issue on OS X Safari - visit [Skiplex UK](https://www.skiplex.co.uk) and you will receive an alert 'Safari can't verify the identity of the website "www.skiplex.co.uk".'.

I have been advised by Comodo and our hosting provider that SSL is setup correctly multiple times. The SSL is indeed working perfectly on all other browsers and operating systems including iOS.

It just seems to be an issue with the SSL on skiplex website. I can connect through to other websites using SSL, such as apple, google, etc.

Feel like I'm getting no where with this issue. Any ideas much appreciated.

**Additional Info**

- I'm using Safari Version 9.0.2. I also know others experiencing same
  issue (on various versions of Safari) so unfortunately issue not
  local to my machine.
- As far as I'm aware this issue does not occur on Safari for Windows.

Comment: What does it show about the root certificate in the chain ("COMODO RSA Certificate Authority")?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Following link is a screenshot after clicking "COMODO RSA Certificate Authority" - http://i.stack.imgur.com/s6obM.png

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this issue with Safari 9. By visiting Skiplex UK everything loads correctly without a SSL cert error.

Here’s what you can do:

- Ty clearing your Safari Cache and Cookie
- Open Keychain Acccess and select Keychain First Aid > Select „Repair“ > Start
- Reboot your Computer.

This sites covers your issue in more detail. http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/26/fix-safari-cant-verify-website-error/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried following your advice and also the steps in article but unfortunately does not fix issue. I'm using Safari Version 9.0.2. I also know others experiencing same issue (on various versions of Safari) so unfortunately issue not local to my machine. Though good to know that not all OS X Safari users are experiencing the issue :)

Comment: Yeah, in some cases it be a server-side-issue, however in this case I guess it's a local issue with your OS X installation. Somehow your root certificates aren't up-to-date due upgrades from OS X version.  Do you also experience these issues with Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Nope - only experience the issue on OS X Safari. All other browsers, including Firefox and Chrome, work fine. Strange!

Comment: Didn't work for me. The Comodo certificates always throw errors under Mac OS 10.8

Comment: @Foliovision: If possible, try updating to the latest macOS X version. macOS 10.8 is no longer supported since September 2015.

Comment: Tom, I don't want to use the latest OS X. 10.8 runs better on this machine. That comment is not stackexchange caliber really. It's the kind of answer you'd get from the manufacturers call centre.